# Redshift extracting data before the last hyphen

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract data before the hyphen as shown below:

```
col_name
apple-orange
apples-oranges
apples-oranges-bananas
```

Expected output:

```
col_name
apple
apples
apples-oranges
```

I tried `split_part` function in Redshift but I am having issues when the row has multiple hyphen

Sample code tried:

```
split_part(col_name,'-',1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_COUNT`,`REGEXP_INSTR` and `SUBSTRING` to achieve this

The SQL would be

```
SELECT substring(col_name,1,regexp_instr(col_name,'-',1,regexp_count(col_name,'-'))-1)
```

Using `REGEXP_COUNT` we can count how many hyphens are in the string.
Then with `REGEXP_INSTR` we can identify what is the position of last hyphen and `SUBSTRING` will give us the first part of the string.

to test I have used

```
WITH test(col_name) AS
(
SELECT 'apples-oranges' UNION
SELECT 'bananas-oranges-mangos-apples' UNION
SELECT 'apples-oranges-bananas')
SELECT col_name,  
       substring(col_name,1,regexp_instr(col_name,'-',1,regexp_count(col_name,'-'))-1) result
  FROM test
```

Output is

```
col_name                        result
apples-oranges                  apples
apples-oranges-bananas          apples-oranges
bananas-oranges-mangos-apples   bananas-oranges-mangos
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a procedure or function to accomplish the 3rd example.

**Example (Oracle)**

```
select LENGTH('apples-blah-blabla') - INSTR(REVERSE('apples-blah-blabla'),'-') from dual;
```

results = `11`

```
select substr('apples-blah-blabla', 1,11) from dual;
```

results = `apples-blah`

Something like this in a procedure:

**SQL Server**

```
@val=select LEN('apples-blah-blabla') - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE('apples-blah-blabla')) 
     from table;

select substr('apples-blah-blabla', 1,@val) from dual;
```

**Oracle**

```
v_val=select LENGTH('apples-blah-blabla') - INSTR(REVERSE('apples-blah-blabla'),'-') 
      from dual;

select substr('apples-blah-blabla', 1,v_val) from dual;
```

Comment: Can be done in Redshift with out a function or procedure, see my answer, OP has Redshift tag

Comment: Nicely done.  Something similar should work on other platforms as well, though I know the OP is asking specifically regarding redshift.